# Rank images from a foreign language site in English Google image search

Tags: seo, google, google-search, google-image-search

I have big medical domain about ECG, with 100 pages.
But all domain is in Slovak language (and slovak online medical market is small),
and I have on domain more than 500 special medical ECG images.
(ECG images are universal for all around the medical world.)

Is the next code the best way to tell Google,
put all image from Slovak domain in english image SERP?
`<img src="ecg-arrhythmia.png" alt="ECG ventricular arrhythmia">`

And is it good for SEO?
To put in "src", and "alt" tag english descrition
when all domain is in Slovak language?

Comment: Unless you have an English site I'm not sure Google is going to rank your images in English image search.   It is more than just seeing the images.   Google wants users to be able to click through and read the associated info.